# Align header with cells whose text is oriented at an angle

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, cells, alignment, orientation

Is there a smart way to align horizontal-text "header" cells with other cells below whose text is oriented at an angle?

This is what I tried. Obviously this looks awful. The "Benefits" and "Caution" headers are not aligned at all with the "category" cells under them.

[image]

Comment: Merge the cells above where you want it to go and center it?

Comment: That will go out of alignment as soon as the height of the row with the tilted text changes. Not to mention that the cell colour won't align nicely regardless (admittedly that is a secondary concern).

Comment: I always prefer "Center across selection" to merging cells. Have you trie that @Jean-FrançoisCorbett? select all the cells above your headers and format them in the color you need and select "Center across selection" in the horizontal alignment dropdown

Comment: from what I know, there is no automated way to do it.   If you really want his layout you will have to perform some manual adjustment for Benefits row.   Alternatively you can just switch the two rows, not what you asked for but conveys the same information clearly

Comment: afaik not possible in Excel - but would it be acceptable to move the "Benefits" and "Caution" row BELOW "the Rabbits, Ducks etc." row? Imho this would even be less ambigious what columns the "Benefits" refer to. Maybe both header rows in a slightly darker color to separate it from the other (data) rows?

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't appear to have an easy way to use cell and border formatting to do what you are looking for. Only thing I could find was to no use the angle so they line up.

An alternate to that would be to insert a text box sized and formatted as you desire to fit the top of the angled headers. You can add a text box from the `Insert` tab, `Text` group.

[image]

You can then resize and format the text box as you wish.

[image]